# How to split a string based on several separators

Tags: python, string, split

i have the following data and it is the element number 1 with index zero in an array `featuresCollectionGeometries` so that `featuresCollectionGeometries[0]` returns the following data
`

```
    ['6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371,6.69222819326484 51.1329081193748,6.69221180776184 51.1329013203209,6.69219149698336 51.1329073049609,6.69217949340067 51.1329244260894,6.69217956546811 51.1329430447612,6.69218526127669 51.1329578171713,6.692200130301 51.1329606289999,6.69220511560768 51.1329581192089,6.69221372090576 51.1329518135339,6.69222707128915 51.132939215911,6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371']
```

so each entry or element in the array is a string that has the aforementioned format.
what i want to accomplish is to separate the longitude values and add them into "longitudeValuesArray" and separate the latitude values and add them to "latitudeValuesArray"
**Note**:

```
    the entries separated by comma represents longitude and latitude. for example, given the above mentioned values
    `longitudeValuesArray should contain['6.69223420722764,6.69222819326484,6.69221180776184,6.69219149698336,6.69217949340067,6.69217956546811,6.69218526127669,6.692200130301,6.69220511560768,6.69221372090576,6.69222707128915,6.69223420722764']
    `latitudeValuesArray should contain['51.1329165124371,51.1329081193748,51.1329013203209,51.1329073049609,51.1329244260894,51.1329430447612,51.1329578171713,51.1329606289999,51.1329581192089,51.1329518135339,51.132939215911,51.1329165124371']
```

please let me know how to split the string that contains values for longitude and latitude to achive my goal

Answer (score 1):

You might use `re.split` from built-in module `re` to split on several seperators

```
import re
data = '6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371,6.69222819326484 51.1329081193748,6.69221180776184 51.1329013203209,6.69219149698336 51.1329073049609,6.69217949340067 51.1329244260894,6.69217956546811 51.1329430447612,6.69218526127669 51.1329578171713,6.692200130301 51.1329606289999,6.69220511560768 51.1329581192089,6.69221372090576 51.1329518135339,6.69222707128915 51.132939215911,6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371'
parts = re.split(' |,', data)
```

where `|` denotes *or*, then use slicing to extract longitudes and latitudes

```
lons = parts[::2]
lats = parts[1::2]
print(lons)
print(lats)
```

output

```
['6.69223420722764', '6.69222819326484', '6.69221180776184', '6.69219149698336', '6.69217949340067', '6.69217956546811', '6.69218526127669', '6.692200130301', '6.69220511560768', '6.69221372090576', '6.69222707128915', '6.69223420722764']
['51.1329165124371', '51.1329081193748', '51.1329013203209', '51.1329073049609', '51.1329244260894', '51.1329430447612', '51.1329578171713', '51.1329606289999', '51.1329581192089', '51.1329518135339', '51.132939215911', '51.1329165124371']
```

Comment: Good point, I like your code without loops.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `featuresCollectionGeometries` has multiple values that each contain rows you showed. In that case, loop over the elements in `featuresCollectionGeometries`, split the data on the comma, and then loop over the longitude, latitude pairs. Split them and append them to their own list.

```
longitude_values = []
latitude_values = []

for i in featuresCollectionGeometries:
    data = i.split(',')
    for longlat in data:
        longitude_values.append(longlat.split(' ')[0])
        latitude_values.append(longlat.split(' ')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split(',')` on entire string  and then `split()` on each entry of latitude and longitude

```
lst =  ['6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371,6.69222819326484 51.1329081193748,6.69221180776184 51.1329013203209,6.69219149698336 51.1329073049609,6.69217949340067 51.1329244260894,6.69217956546811 51.1329430447612,6.69218526127669 51.1329578171713,6.692200130301 51.1329606289999,6.69220511560768 51.1329581192089,6.69221372090576 51.1329518135339,6.69222707128915 51.132939215911,6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371']

res = [float(y) for x in lst[0].split(',') for y in x.split()]
lng, lat = res[::2], res[1::2]

print(lng)
#[6.69223420722764, 6.69222819326484, 6.69221180776184, 6.69219149698336, 6.69217949340067, 6.69217956546811, 6.69218526127669, 6.692200130301, 6.69220511560768, 6.69221372090576, 6.69222707128915, 6.69223420722764]
print(lat)
#[51.1329165124371, 51.1329081193748, 51.1329013203209, 51.1329073049609, 51.1329244260894, 51.1329430447612, 51.1329578171713, 51.1329606289999, 51.1329581192089, 51.1329518135339, 51.132939215911, 51.1329165124371]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```py
orig_list = ['6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371,6.69222819326484 51.1329081193748,6.69221180776184 51.1329013203209,6.69219149698336 51.1329073049609,6.69217949340067 51.1329244260894,6.69217956546811 51.1329430447612,6.69218526127669 51.1329578171713,6.692200130301 51.1329606289999,6.69220511560768 51.1329581192089,6.69221372090576 51.1329518135339,6.69222707128915 51.132939215911,6.69223420722764 51.1329165124371']

split_list = orig_list[0].split(',')

long_list = [value.split()[0] for value in split_list]
lat_list  = [value.split()[1] for value in split_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main_list = featuresCollectionGeometries[0].split(',')

longitudeValuesArray = [float(elem_lat.split()[0]) for elem_lat in main_list]

latitudeValuesArray = [float(elem_lat.split()[1]) for elem_lat in main_list]
```